# Onboard clipboard manager in Windows doesn't show preview (even for text entries)

Tags: windows-11, clipboard

Using Win+V it's possible to use the built-in Windows clipboard manager. I noticed in my Windows 11 installation it often displays "No preview available" even for simple text entries. Sometimes there is an entry in between that gets displayed, but most other entries show "No preview available".

[image]

I tried to replicate the behavior by clicking "clear all" and adding a bunch of text and graphical entries but so far I had no luck. So far this only happened during regular usage (but then quite frequently). I also tried to reset the clipboard manager by activating/deactivating that didn't do the trick. Also tried clearing it, but that didn't help either.

Note: I'm not using the clipboard sync ("Share across devices"):

[image]

Not sure if this is Windows 11 specific, I never had this kind of behavior on a Windows 10 machine. Can anyone confirm this or have an idea what's causing this and/or how to fix it (until this hopefully gets resolved by an update)?

Comment: On my main machine, Win+V brings up clipboard history properly each time. On another, lesser used machine, clipboard history was not enabled. But overall it seems to work fine. Is your Windows 11 up to date?  22000.778 ?

Comment: For other reasons, I was cleaning up my main machine and I see Clipboard History was reduced to just what happened in the last hour. It still works properly in Win 11. But I have learned not to rely on clipboard history.

Comment: Yeah, Windows is up to date (I did the routine system checks as well)...  not sure when the problem started but I think it was there from the very beginning.

Comment: I will keep looking. Lots of documents today and Clipboard History is building correctly and normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that a different profile did not have the same problems. So as a workaround I created a new profile and migrated my user data to the new profile. Not the easiest solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've had something similar happen on Windows 10.
Turning off clipboard sync and clearing the history solved it for me, never had issues since.
Not 100% sure it was the same problem you are having though. Let me know if it helped!

[This link solved it for me on Win 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/clipboard-history-not-working-or-showing#:%7E:text=The%20first%20thing%20you%20should,on%20clicking%20Windows%20%2B%20V%20hotkey.)
[This is similar info for Win 11](https://wethegeek.com/windows-11-clipboard-history-not-working/#:%7E:text=Clear%20the%20Clipboard%20Data,%E2%80%9CClear%20clipboard%20data%E2%80%9D%20option.)

Comment: I don't use sync, and I tried clearing the history, that unfortunately did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "something similar", could you elaborate?

Comment: Something similar: 
I am using Win 10 and have sync turned on. But I also had no previews showing. I don't remember if clicking a preview did paste the copied item.

Have you tried the 2nd link for Win 11? 

Which programs are you using when there is a preview available?

Comment: yeah I tried it, non of the solutions worked for me though (I think the solutions are based on the premise that the clipboard manager is not working at all). But it gave me the idea to try a different local profile which worked so I just ended up using the workaround. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just glad you solved it! Still weird that this had to be done, seems to me that maybe your registry files are corrupt. Unfortunately I have no clue how to test this or know which part of the registry to rename. I do this all the time for non-windows software related issues.

Comment: I guess the "database" (or however windows stores the entries) was messed up. I don't understand why clearing it didn't make a difference. Since other users are ok I'm wondering if the same "DB" is used for every system user or if they are independent of each other.

Comment: I am pretty sure this stuff is not stored in a 'database' but rather in your RAM.
(source: https://qr.ae/pv4n6N [Where is the clipboard data stored on Windows 10?]) 

https://qr.ae/pv4nzy [Copy Paste not working -> Solution]
You could try this, if still wanting to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't preview when I copied out of a specific program (Inkscape), so I just pasted my text into Windows Editor and recopied, then it previewed properly.
Seems to be the programs fault/issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).